# Why can't print the passwd by System.out.println(passwd)?The passwd was getten by Console.readPasswd()

Tags: java, console

I got a passwd by Console.readPasswd().When I save it in char array (char[] passwd) and use System.out.println(passwd) .The result is

[image]

I input is "123".

```java
import java.io.Console;

public class ConsoleTest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Console console = System.console();
        String username = console.readLine("user name :");
        System.out.println("user name ="+username);
        char[] password = console.readPassword("passwd:");
        System.out.println("password="+password);
    }
}
```

But when save the passwd in String passwd(I know it's not recommended)

```java
import java.io.Console;

public class ConsoleTest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Console console = System.console();
        String username = console.readLine("user name :");
        System.out.println("user name ="+username);
        String password = new String(console.readPassword("passwd:"));
        System.out.println("password="+ password);
    }
}
```

It can be accurately print:

[image]

Why?

Comment: the meaning of reading it as a password is to keep it secret. printing it open for all to see, isn't keeping it secret

Comment: In the first case you are printing the address of the array, you can use `Arrays.toString(password)` if you want to print the array

Answer (score 0):

Printing a char array directly using `System.out.println` will print the object representation of the array, hence the `[C@232204a1`.
In fact, even that representation tells you that it is a char array, as the prefix is `[C`, the `[` indicating the printed object is an array, with the type being `C`, a char. For more, [see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()).

You need to convert it to a string like in the second example you posted in order for it to be in a human readable format (ignoring all questions of *should* it be in a human readable format.